# Insight into Collections removeAll method

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of size ~200k..I am facing some issues while filtering the list.

Here is the implementation:

```
public List<> filterList(List<> listToBeFiltered){
List<> removeElementsFromList = listToBeFiltered.parallelStream()
                                    .filter(//some filtering logic)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
listToBeFiltered.removeAll(removeElementsFromList);
return listToBeFiltered;
}
```

The problem I face with the code is that the program will remain stuck at the removeAll statement when the removeElementsFromList approaches the size of listToBeFiltered. Any insight/alternate solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `x.removeAll(y)` operation is *O(n×m)*, where *n* is the size of the collection `x`, and *m* is the size of the collection `y` (i.e., *O(|x|×|y|)*).

The `removeAll` method is basically just iterating over the entire list for each element in `y`, checking if each element in `x` happens to be equal, and removing it if so. It would be much more efficient if you could do that in one pass.

Assuming you're using Java 8, there's a much more efficient way to do this:

```
List<Integer> xs = new ArrayList<>();
// TODO: initialize xs with a bunch of values
List<Integer> ys = new ArrayList<>();
// TODO: initialize ys with a bunch of values
Set<Integer> ysSet = new HashSet<>(ys);
List<Integer> xsPrime = xs.stream()
    .filter(x -> !ysSet.contains(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For for `xs` of size 100k and `ys` of size `66k`, using `removeAll` took about 5500ms, whereas using the above method only took about 8ms. I would expect the difference to be even more pronounced when you scale up to 200k due to the quadratic complexity of `removeAll`.

In contrast, the complexity of the filter version used above is going to be *O(n+m)*, since it's *O(m)* to build the `HashSet` of all the values in `ys`, and then *O(n)* to iterate over all the values of `xs` to make sure none are contained in the new `ysSet`. (This is of course assuming that a `HashSet` lookup is *O(1)*.)

---

Looking back at your question again, I realize you're already using `filter`... In that case, I suggest just inverting your filter logic, and then resetting the passed-in list's values to the filtered values:

```
public List<> filterList(List<> listToBeFiltered){
    List<> filteredList = listToBeFiltered.parallelStream()
        .filter(/* some inverted filtering logic */)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    listToBeFiltered.clear();
    listToBeFiltered.addAll(filteredList);
    return listToBeFiltered;
}
```

If you don't need to mutate the original list, then you can just return `filteredList` directly. (That would be my preferred solution anyway.)

---

I just ran my tests again, and this time I added another version that uses a loop instead of streams:

```
Set<Integer> ysSet = new HashSet<>(ys);
List<Integer> xsPrime = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer x : xs) {
    if (!ysSet.contains(x)) {
        xsPrime.add(x);
    }
}
return xsPrime;
```

This version finished in about 7ms instead of 8ms. Since that's only marginally faster than the stream version (especially considering the original version using `removeAll` was 3 orders of magnitude slower), I'd stick with the stream version—especially because you can take advantage of parallelism there (as you're already doing with `parallelStream`).